# Convert this SQL Server query to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have the following in a SQL Server query which I have to convert to Oracle sp

```
DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(ss, -L_LAST_TIME, TR.TR_DATETIME))) AS TRDATE,
```

Essentially you subtract `L_LAST_TIME` seconds from `TR_DATETIME` and then truncate the time part and keep only the date part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide intervals:

```
select trunc(TR.TR_DATETIME - interval L_LAST_TIME SECOND) AS TRDATE
```

or

```
select trunc(TR.TR_DATETIME - NUMTODSINTERVAL(L_LAST_TIME, 'SECOND')) AS TRDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do arithmetic with dates in Oracle.

```
select trunc(tr.tr_time - (l_last_time/86400)) as trdate
from tr
/
```

Dividing `l_last_time` by 86400 turns a number of seconds into a fraction of day.  Subtracing it from the `tr_time` column gives you a new, earlier date.  Truncating a date removes the time component.